# What differences exist between .update_one(:$set=>params) and .update_one(params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

What differences exist between `.update_one(:$set=>params)` and `.update_one(params)`?

What would happen if I used `.update_one(:$set=>params)` instead of `.update_one(params)` in the last line of the code below?

```
def update(params) 
  @number=params[:number].to_i
  @first_name=params[:first_name] 
  @last_name=params[:last_name] 
  @secs=params[:secs].to_i
  @group=params[:group]
  @gender=params[:gender]

  params.slice!(:number, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :group, :secs)

  self.class.collection
   .find(_id: BSON::ObjectId.from_string(@id))
   .update_one(params)
end
```

Comment: Is this using MongoDB? If so, maybe update the tags on the question to make it a bit clearer?